# Async using inside sub functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have one main function which as two sub functions a() and b().

```
function main() {
a();
b();
}
```

How can I use async module in this. I want a() and b() to run parallely.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel

Use the parallel method.

But notice that parallel is misleading there. In fact the will not run in parallel because node is single-threaded. What will happen is that if the function are async, the first one will be started and start itself an async operation, the second one will then be started, and it will wait for the callbacks to be called. When both have called there callback, the callback of async#parallel will be called. But it makes no sense to execute to synchronous functions in async#parallel, as they will just run sequentially.

Async is for IO operations which involve requests to other processes like database. It allows node to execute a b() function while a() waits for the request to the database to returns, so it is "non-blocking". But it does not allow b() to execute instructions at the same time as a(). If your a() function is just a sequence of synchronous instructions, they will just execute until the function returns, and then only it will check for the event loop and execute b() if called by a callback for example.

If you want to really do work in parallel (to use multicore processor for example) use the cluster module provided natively in node. It will allow you to spawn several processes. But you should not use it to execute singles functions in parallel, but rather to spawn several clones of your server process, or to execute heavy jobs in other processes in the background, so they won't block your server process.g